# collision between two objects

Tags: collision-resolution

to test collision i am using intersect function.

```
if(this.getBounds_ball().intersects(this.getBounds_rect())) 
{
```

but the problem is i dont know how to test where the ball is collision from.
i was thinking it will have a if statment inside to check if ball is collsion from left. another for right, top and bottom. so 4 if statments? but i dont know how to code it. any ideas? 
any ideas?

Comment: Asking a broad, "how-to-do-this" question is generally not permitted on this site; please see the [faq].  However, more specific questions about pong, brick-breaker et al. are thoroughly covered.  Try this search, see if it helps you find what you need.  [Pong Collision](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=pong+collision)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution but I've used something similar.
I found how much one object is overlapping the other and adjust accordingly.

```
xOverlap = boundsA.X - boundsB.X;
yOverlap = boundsA.Y - boundsB.Y;
```

then just watch those variables and you should be able to see where you stand.
There's probably a better way though I'm still new.

Comment: ah i c, the overlaping is making sense but how to test if ball is touch it from left. <br/>i looked online for this but cant find any thing what i am looking for. all tutorial are just for basic intersects(). if you have a good link let me know.